# Remove row from a numpy array according to some condition and concatenate result

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have a list of numpy arrays and I wanted to remove a row according to some condition.
Lets suppose I have the following list of numpy arrays and I want to delete the rows which contain an item that is > 8.

```
test = [np.array([[2,2,4],[10,3,5],[1,2,4,],[1,2,4]]),
        np.array([[1,2,3],[1,3,5],[6,3,1],[9,1,2]])]

for i in test:
    z = np.argwhere(i>8)
    print(z)#[[1 0]] and [[3 0]]
    a1 = np.delete(i,z,axis=0)
    print(a1)
```

This for loop skips the numpy array of index[0]. *How can Ifix this?*
**Returns**:

```
[[1 2 4]
 [1 2 4]]
[[1 3 5]
 [6 3 1]]
```

Desirable **Return**:

```
[[2,2,4]
 [1 2 4]
 [1 2 4]]
[[1,2,3]
 [1 3 5]
 [6 3 1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, you want to remove row with index 1 from the first array,
and row with index 3 from the second array.
So use those indices when executing `np.delete`:

```
a1 = np.delete(i, z[0][0], axis=0)
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. But just to clarify, to see if I got it right. Even though I put axis=0 I should exemplify  that it is the row I want,by adding this [0]  in order to remove it, is that right?

Comment: Yes, because you do `np.delete(i, [0, 1], axis=0)`, it will remove the *multiple rows* with those indices, 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

`np.argwhere` will return both indices, but we're only interested in the rows:

```py
np.argwhere(i > 8)[:, 0]
```

But really, we're only interested in *unique* rows, so we can take care of that too:

```py
np.unique(np.argwhere(i > 8)[:, 0])
```

Altogether we get:

```py
test = [np.array([[2,2,4],[10,3,5],[1,2,4,],[1,2,4]]),np.array([[1,2,3],[1,3,5],[6,3,1],[9,1,2]])]


for i in test:
    z = np.unique(np.argwhere(i>8)[:, 0])
    a1 = np.delete(i,z,axis=0)
    print(a1)

#[[2 2 4]
# [1 2 4]
# [1 2 4]]
#[[1 2 3]
# [1 3 5]
# [6 3 1]]
```